# Transfer data from one mysql to another mysql(installed along with wampserver) installed in same computer

Tags: php, mysql, wampserver

Please be kind to clear my doubt.
I am a beginner.

I think i have 2 mysql installed !!!

I have Installed MySQL server 5.5 in program files before months.
I have created many tables in it

But recently I started using php .I installed wampserver. I know how to connect  PHP to the MySQL that came along with wampserver.Its user name is "root" and password is (no password) and servername is "localhost".

But i don't know how to connect php to the MySQL that I installed 1st which has all my tables and data. I don't know its user name or hostname but I know its password.

> 1) So could anyone tell me how to connect PHP to the MySQL 5.5 which has
>   all my data.
>
> 2) Could you tell me how to transfer the tables in MySQL 5.5 to the MySQL
>   in wampserver

{ I open that MySQL by clicking  " wampserver(in task bar)-->MySQL-->MySQL console}

Could anyone tell me what is meant by username ,password ,servername.

How to find the username ,password ,servername.

Comment: How did you create the tables in the mysql you installed first, if you do not know the username? The host name is simple: it is also localhost.

Comment: If you have wamp then there is option to export your db as csv, sql etc. Select sql and get the file containing whole database and you can import that in any mysql

Answer (score 0):

1. By default - hostname=localhost / username=root
2. to transfer, login to your panel and click export. it will download an sql file

Comment: I didn't understand  . "to transfer, login to your panel and click export. it will download an sql file" . where to login ? Shoud i start mysql command line client.

Answer (score 0):

Ok there are a number of unknowns here.

If you had the non-wampserver MYSQL installed first, it is likely that that MYSQL instance is being started automatically at boot time. If this is the case then even though you think you are using the WAMPServer version of MYSQL you are not.

Check using the "services snapin" which MYSQL is actually started :-

How to start the services snapin,

```
WINDOWS Key+R
Enter "services.msc"
Press the OK button
```

Look for a service called `wampmysqld` or `wampmysqld64` these are the 2 possible names of the WAMPServer installed MYSQL Service.

You will also find another service called `MYSQL` this will be the MYSQL that you had originally installed.

Now if the `MYSQL` service is `started` that is the MYSQL that you will be talking to when you use ANY App on you PC including WAMPServer.

Now you need to make sure that the MYSQL service is running and the `wampmysqld` service is not!

Now you can run phpMyAdmin from the WAMPServer install. Use this to EXPORT each of your databases. Only EXPORT your databases, do not EXPORT any databases that you did not create as theses will be MYSQL's own databases which it uses to control and manage iteself. These databases are not transferable between version so leave them alone.

Now once you have EXPORTED (Backed Up) each of your database, You can use the Services snapin again to STOP the MYSQL  Service. Once that is stopped you can START the `wampmysqld` or `wampmysqld64` service. Now you will be using the MYSQL that came with WAMPServer.

You can now go back to phpMyAdmin and IMPORT your databases one by one. Once this is complete, check they are all there.

Now you can Uninstall the other MYSQL so it does not get in the way ever again.

Alternatively, using the services snapin you can set the old MYSQL Service to a diabled state, you can keep it for a while, but it will not autostart again, so if you have forgotten to back something up you can go back and try and EXPORT whatever database yo forget originally.

How to set MYSQL Service to Disabled using Service snapin.

```
Left click on the MYSQL Service, it should show a menu.
Click on Properties.
Change the "Startup Type" to Disabled.
```